# Getting defined variables for PHP error handler

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling

Old versions of PHP passed all defined variables and stack to a custom error handler defined with

```
function myHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $vars, $trace)
{
 .....  
}

set_error_handler("myHandler");
```

Later on it was changed and the error handler received error context, where all variables were accessible.

```
function myHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
 .....  
}
```

There is no errorcontext available right now and even debug_backtrace() function returns list without arguments:

```
[
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/includes\/dbFunci.inc.php",
        "line": 133,
        "function": "query",
        "class": "mysqli",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/includes\/dbFunci.inc.php",
        "line": 740,
        "function": "performQuery"
    },
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/includes\/auditFunc.inc.php",
        "line": 293,
        "function": "insertSQLRow"
    },
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/inscubator.cz\/pinsFunc.inc.php",
        "line": 92,
        "function": "writeAudit2"
    },
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/inscubator.cz\/savePin.php",
        "line": 44,
        "function": "savePin"
    }
]
```

What is nowadays approach of getting error moment defined variables and debug_trace with arguments?

Comment: [debug_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace) should still show the arguments, if you don't specify `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS`. If this doesn't happen for you, can you add [a working example](https://3v4l.org/O1Du4) to your question and specify the PHP version you're using?